# Create a user node in firebase database Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to create a node in the firebase database like below:

```
{
"Users" : {
"SktNBDO4pOgS6wNfFIc5lV8p4u73" : {
  "Email" : "user@email.com",
  "Name" : "Name Surname"
    }
  }
}
```

the code I'm using is:

```
user = auth.CurrentUser;

//Init Firebase
dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference("Users").Child(user.Uid).Child("Name");

var postData = new UserListItemViewModel
            {
                Name = "Name Surname",
                Email = "user@email.com",
            };

dataBase.SetValue(postData.Name);
```

what I want to do is to set all the UserListItemViewModel into the database, like:

```
user = auth.CurrentUser;

            //Init Firebase
            dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference("Users").Child(user.Uid).Child("Name");

            Dictionary<string, UserListItemViewModel> userData = new Dictionary<string, UserListItemViewModel>
            {
                {
                    user.Uid,
                    new UserListItemViewModel
                    {
                        Name = "Name Surname",
                        Email = "user@email.com",
                    }
                }
            };                

            dataBase.SetValue(userData);
```

The problem with the above code is that `userData` should be `Java.Lang.Object`.

I came in this solution following a tutorial in Java suggesting

```
Map<string, UserListItemViewModel> userData = new HashMap(user.Uid, new UserListItemViewModel
{ 
    Name = "Name Surname",
    Email = "user@email.com",
})`
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar function with FCM, you can refer to the following code：

```
 private DatabaseReference mMsgDatabaseReference;

 //************************************

 var taskSnapShot = (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)snapshot;

 Android.Net.Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapShot.DownloadUrl;
 FriendlyMessage msg = new FriendlyMessage(null,mUserName,downloadUrl.ToString());
 mMsgDatabaseReference.Push().SetValue(FriendlyMessage.MsgModelToMap(msg));
```

Method `MsgModelToMap`:

```
 public static HashMap MsgModelToMap(FriendlyMessage msg)
    {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();

        map.Put("text", msg.text);
        map.Put("name", msg.name);
        map.Put("photoUrl", msg.photoUrl);
        map.Put("UId", msg.UId);

        return map;
    }
```

FriendlyMessage.cs

```
 class FriendlyMessage : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
{
    public String text;
    public String name;
    public String photoUrl;

    public String UId;
    public void setUid(String Id) {
        this.UId = Id;
    }
    public String getUId() {
        return UId;
    }

    private static readonly MyParcelableCreator<FriendlyMessage> _create = new MyParcelableCreator<FriendlyMessage>(GetMessage);

    //[ExportField("CREATOR")]
    [ExportField("CREATOR")]
    public static MyParcelableCreator<FriendlyMessage> Create()
    {
        return _create;
    }

    private static FriendlyMessage GetMessage(Parcel parcel)
    {
        FriendlyMessage msg = new FriendlyMessage();

        msg.text = parcel.ReadString();
        msg.name = parcel.ReadString();
        msg.photoUrl = parcel.ReadString();
        msg.UId = parcel.ReadString();
        return msg;
    }
    public FriendlyMessage()
    {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.UId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl()
    {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl)
    {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, [GeneratedEnum] ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteString(text);
        dest.WriteString(name);
        dest.WriteString(photoUrl);
        dest.WriteString(UId);
    }

    public static HashMap MsgModelToMap(FriendlyMessage msg)
    {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();

        map.Put("text", msg.text);
        map.Put("name", msg.name);
        map.Put("photoUrl", msg.photoUrl);
        map.Put("UId", msg.UId);

        return map;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "name = " + name +" text = " + text + " photoUrl= " + photoUrl+ " UId = " + UId;
    }

    public static FriendlyMessage MapToMsgModel(DataSnapshot snapShot)
    {
        FriendlyMessage msg = new FriendlyMessage();

        if (snapShot.GetValue(true) == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        msg.UId = snapShot.Key;
        msg.text = snapShot.Child("text")?.GetValue(true)?.ToString();
        msg.name = snapShot.Child("name")?.GetValue(true)?.ToString();
        msg.photoUrl = snapShot.Child("photoUrl")?.GetValue(true)?.ToString();

        return msg;

    }

    public  bool Equal_obj(object obj)
    {
        var message = obj as FriendlyMessage;
        return message != null &&
               text == message.text &&
               name == message.name &&
               photoUrl == message.photoUrl &&
               UId == message.UId;
    }
}
```